# dod cac reader setup ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, repository, downloads

I read that I need to download cackey from forge.mil but the download isn't there any more.  How can I get my CAC reader working now?  Is there a sudo apt-get command for it?  Does someone have a copy of the file?  Is it located else where because I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot access DISA's Forge.mil website, (Because it requires CAC access)

You can Download the 32bit Deb file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8JoV2w_9hiceUoyeFBqSTV6a0U/edit?usp=sharing).
  
MD5: 37398d413221b7d6c6ee539978feec47
  
SHA1: 3ccfc97610b1b3503084caa7f1924c52d2f1a1b4

Or, the 64 bit Deb [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8JoV2w_9hicRGQ0TFQ5UEpwSkE/edit?usp=sharing).
  
 MD5: 3935d1376ae7175f9814505c59a917f7

SHA1: 153b30d025869679238444e2ef0545ed7185f4f8

Comment: you are the man

Comment: I'll take that to mean it worked. :)  Also, for what it's worth, 12.04 & 12.10 gave me issues accessing Enterprise E-mail OWA, but 13.04 works like a charm. I think it's an issue with the way the 12's select the cert.

Comment: @Arguvision what did you do to access the EE?  I go the site, hit ok, enter my pin, and then get an error screen.  I am using 13.04 as well.

Comment: I haven't done anything special. From a fresh install, I followed the steps I laid out at http://askubuntu.com/questions/285543/how-do-i-install-and-configure-a-security-card-cac-reader-for-ubuntu-13-04 . Take a look at it and see if you're missing a step. Also, once you receive an error message you need to close firefox before you try again, or you'll just keep getting an error. If it will allow you to chose a cert, make sure you select the "e-mail" cert or it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done and I successfully accessed AKO, enterprise email, and even the disa site for cackey.

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
3. Open a terminal and type the following: sudo apt-get install libpcsclite-dev pcscd pcsc-tools libccid build-essential autoconf
4. Restart your computer
5. Open a terminal and type: pcsc_scan [check to make sure you have an output and it does not get stuck on Scanning present readers....]
6. Go to Ubuntu Software Center and search for coolkey and install
7. Download the DoD Configuration Extension for Firefox @ http://www.forge.mil/Resources-Firefox.html (Let it install the plugin and restart; don't worry about all of the errors just click through them and restart your browser).
8. Go to Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Encryption > Security (You should see your CAC id visible)
9. Go to AKO ect...

Comment: I get an error when I go to login to AKO.  SSL peer can't verify your certificate.

Comment: @Cameron - FYI, Coolkey only works with older cards. For the newer (144k) cards you need cackey.

Comment: And, you don't need step 7

Answer (score 0):

For what I read, what you need is some authorization to be able to download. See [How can I get access to Forge.mil (CAC users)?](http://www.forge.mil/Faqs.html#faqs10)

Comment: It says you need your CAC to register.  That puts me in a conundrum since my system is Linux only.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to trust the download links in @Argsvision's answer, or just need to use a CAC only briefly. You can use the USAF's Lightweight Portable Security (LPS) ISO to access forge.mil and other CAC-only sites. Get it from http://www.spi.dod.mil/lipose.htm After using LPS to download the CAC files from forge.mil you can then follow the steps in @Argsvision's answer.

You can thus use the LPS ISO to "bootstrap" a computer without any other computer that can use a CAC or trusting anyone except the spi.dod.mil site.